# True values in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

Is the meaning of a true value defined in the Scheme Standard? Or does the implementator of the Scheme evaluator have the choice to define it as:
`(define (true? x) (eq? x #t))`?

Comment: My reading of the [Scheme Specification](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) indicates that a true value is defined as `#t`.  While you could certainly define `true` to mean the same thing, it's non-standard, and redefining `#t` to mean something else (or to disallow it) is not supported by the specification.

Comment: There's no `true?` function in Scheme.

Comment: @Barmar: It's easy enough to write one, as the OP has demonstrated.

Comment: Note that any value other than `#f` is treated as true by all the conditional operations.

Comment: `(define (true? x) (eq? x #t))` defines a procedure. That's a kind of value, but it's not serving as true; we have to **call** it to test whether an object is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Do Scheme Standards Define Meaning for True Values?

Yes, the meaning of "true" is well-defined in Scheme.

There are a number of Scheme standards, but in all of them there are only two boolean objects; these have the *external representations* `#t` and `#f`. R7RS also requires that the boolean objects have the alternate external representations `#true` and `#false`. But, in a conditional test all values evaluate as true except `#f` (and `#false` in the case of R7RS). Other lisps, notably Common Lisp, may have different concepts of truthiness.

[R5RS 6.3.1 Booleans:](https://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.1)

> Of all the standard Scheme values, only `#f` counts as false in
> conditional expressions. Except for `#f`, all standard Scheme values,
> including `#t`, pairs, the empty list, symbols, numbers, strings,
> vectors, and procedures, count as true.

[R6RS 5.7 Boolean values:](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_5.7)

> Although there is a separate boolean type, any Scheme value can be
> used as a boolean value for the purpose of a conditional test. In a
> conditional test, all values count as true in such a test except for
> `#f`. This report uses the word “true” to refer to any Scheme value except `#f`, and the word “false” to refer to `#f`.

R7RS 6.3 Booleans:

> The standard boolean objects for true and false are written as `#t` and
> `#f`. Alternatively, they can be written `#true` and
> `#false`, respectively. What really matters, though, are the objects that the Scheme conditional expressions (`if`, `cond`, `and`, `or`, `when`,
> `unless`, `do`) treat as true or false....
>
> Of all the Scheme values, only `#f` counts as false in conditional
> expressions. All other Scheme values, including `#t`, count as true.

### Can Implementations Use Different Definitions for True?

> Or does the implementator of the Scheme evaluator have the choice to
> define it as: `(define (true? x) (eq? x #t))`?

There is no `true?` predicate defined in any Scheme standard. Such a predicate defined as in OP example would be misleading in the most common use cases for true/false values, i.e., in conditional expressions:

```
> (define (true? x) (eq? x #t))
> (true? '())
#f
> (if '()
      "true? does not expect this"
      "true? expects this")
"true? does not expect this"
```

The above procedure tests whether a value is the boolean `#t`, but not whether it is true. Any implementation that does not treat all non-`#f` values (including `#t`) as true is not a conforming implementation of Scheme. An implementation that uses the OP definition of `true?` to establish the meaning of "true" within the implementation would be nonconforming.

One could define `true?` as follows:

```
> (define (true? x) (not (not x)))
> (true? '())
#t
> (true? #t)
#t
> (true? #f)
#f
```

This would answer the question of whether a value will test as true or false in a conditional expression.

Note that there is also a `boolean?` predicate in Scheme that tests whether a value is a boolean value:

```
> (true? #t)
#t
> (boolean? #t)
#t
> (true? 0)
#t
> (boolean? 0)
#f
> (true? #f)
#f
> (boolean? #f)
#t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define such a function, but it would be better to use

```
(define (true? x)
  (not (eq? x #f)))
```

This matches the logic of all the built-in conditional operations. As explained in Section 3.2 of [R<sup>7</sup>RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf):

> Although there is a separate boolean type, any Scheme
> value can be used as a boolean value for the purpose of
> a conditional test. As explained in section 6.3, all values
> count as true in such a test except for `#f`.

`#t` is the canonical true value that's returned when only a boolean value is needed.

Comment: The representation might not be the same, but the way they're used should be the same.

Comment: The actual data. For instance, the metacircular evaluator could implement integers as lists (the length of the list is the value), while the underlying implementation could use hardware integers.

Comment: When you're writing a metacircular evaluator, you can choose how much of the underlying implementation to use directly, versus the parts that you define in your evaluator.

Comment: but how can you change the representation of the truth values?

Comment: that is impossible, isn't it?

Comment: When you're writing your own interpreter, you have control over the representation of everything.