# Proper way to pass a boolean function

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I thought to see if something was "true" in scheme I could do the following:

```
(lambda (x) (= x #t)))
```

However, that gives me some sort of error, and I fell back to use something like the following which works (for now):

```
(lambda (x) x)
```

What would be the closest to a `isTrue` function in scheme similar to the python:

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Also, why doesn't doing something like `(= 4 #t)` work? Does `=` only work on numeric types in scheme?

Comment: You can just do `(define (true? x) (not (not x)))`. You might be interested [in this Q & A.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393506/true-values-in-scheme/66393885#66393885)

Comment: `!!x` is pretty cool, I like that one!

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the other answer at the linked Q & A uses `(not (eq? #f))`, i.e., compares with `#f` instead of `#t`, since the only falsey values in Scheme (or Racket) are `#f`. Note that Scheme does not have the `false?` predicate; that is a Racketism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing if something is `false` in Racket, we have the `false?` predicate, but curiously we don't have a `true?` predicate - it's easy enough to implement, though:

```
(define (true? exp)
  (not (false? exp)))
```

In case you're wondering, in Scheme the *only* `false` value is `#f`, everything else is considered truthy. And you're right, the `=` procedure is used exclusively for numbers; if you need a more general equality comparison simply use `equals?`. This works now:

```
(equal? 4 #t)
=> #f
```

Clearly `4` is not equal to `#t`, but anyway `4` (or any other number for that matter) is considered *truthy*:

```
(if 4 'ok 'nope)
=> 'ok
```